# Getting FileNotFoundException When Trying to Share MP3 Through Implicit Intent Using Using FileProvider

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception, android-fileprovider

I'm trying to share an MP3 file from my android's internal files (the root of which is `getFilesDir()`) to another application using an `ACTION_VIEW` implicit intent. The MP3 file was originally stored in my app's `/raw` folder, but I copied it over to my app's internal files.

I have verified that the file exists using `file.exists()`. When I use a FileProvider to construct a content URI for the file and use that content URI as the data in an implicit intent, however, I get `FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOTDIR` when I try to start the implicit intent.

I have tried changing the FileProvider's authority, and I've looked into [Android's specifications for sharing a media file using intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#PlayMedia) and ensured that my implicit intent conforms to the standards.

Here is the output from the log window when the error occurs:

```
23349-23349/? D/MusicLifecycle: com.google.android.music.ui.playback.AudioPreviewActivity generated event: Activity created
23349-23349/? W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open content://com.example.selfcareapplication.fileprovider/meditation-files/breathing-meditation.mp3: java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOTDIR (Not a directory)
1844-2784/? W/ActivityManager: Permission Denial: opening provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from (null) (pid=1694, uid=1013) that is not exported from UID 10099
1694-2151/? E/MediaPlayerService: Couldn't open fd for content://com.example.selfcareapplication.fileprovider/meditation-files/breathing-meditation.mp3
23349-23349/? E/MediaPlayerNative: Unable to create media player
23349-23349/? D/AudioPreviewActivity: Failed to open file: java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
```

Here is the code I have to get the file, create the FileProvider, and start the intent:

```
Intent openMeditationFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File testFile = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "meditation-files\\breathing-meditation.mp3");

//check if file was written to internal memory. It prints "FILE WAS OUTPUT!"
if(testFile.exists()) {
     Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FILE WAS OUTPUT!");
} else {
     Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FILE WAS NOT OUTPUT!!!");
}

//create content URI using FileProvider and the testFile
Uri meditationFileContentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this.getApplicationContext(), "com.example.selfcareapplication.fileprovider", testFile);
openMeditationFileIntent.setDataAndType(meditationFileContentUri, "audio/*"); 
openMeditationFileIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

//try to open implicit intent using content URI as its data: 
if(openMeditationFileIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
     startActivity(openMeditationFileIntent);
} else {
     Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Could not resolve activity");
}
```

This is my manifest:

```
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.selfcareapplication.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

And this is my file_paths.xml file:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="meditation-files" path="meditation-files/"/>
</paths>
```

**EDIT:**

I was able to get this working!
Per the suggestion from @CommonsWare, I changed the MIME Type to '"audio/mpeg"', which is the MIME type for MP3s.

I also took out the hypens in the path names. Doing this seemed to cause that prevented MP3 file from being properly written to 'getFilesDir() + "meditationPaths"' since checking 'file.exists()' on the MP3's path would return false. Changing the '\'s in the paths to '/'s fixed this problem.

That said, when I did some further testing later, I found that both '\' and '/' allowed the MP3 to be written properly... so I am not absolutely certain what went wrong my first time through. I would just recommend using 'File.separator' to ensure you automatically use the correct separator for the environment your program is running in.

Here is the final code to get the file, create the FileProvider, and start the intent:

```
Intent openMeditationFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File testFile = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "meditationFiles" + Path.separator + "breathingMeditation.mp3");

//check if file was written to internal memory. It prints "FILE WAS OUTPUT!"
if(testFile.exists()) {
     Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FILE WAS OUTPUT!");
} else {
     Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FILE WAS NOT OUTPUT!!!");
}

//create content URI using FileProvider and the testFile
Uri meditationFileContentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this.getApplicationContext(), "com.example.selfcareapplication.fileprovider", testFile);
openMeditationFileIntent.setDataAndType(meditationFileContentUri, "audio/mpeg"); 
openMeditationFileIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

//try to open implicit intent using content URI as its data: 
if(openMeditationFileIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
     startActivity(openMeditationFileIntent);
} else {
     Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Could not resolve activity");
}
```

I also had to change my file-paths.xml file to reflect the change in the folder name:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="meditationFiles" path ="meditationFiles"/>
</paths>
```

Comment: Replace `"audio/*"` with the real MIME type. You might also try not using hyphens. Otherwise, what you have looks good. `Permission Denial: opening provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from (null) (pid=1694, uid=1013) that is not exported from UID 10099` makes it seem like your `setFlags()` call is being ignored, though I can't explain why that would happen.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I was able to get it working! But I'm a bit confused as to why it's working now. I took out the hyphens, but that started making 'file.exists()' return false until I changed the '\\' in the paths to '/' (which I think is the correct separator anyway). When I did some testing on the hypenated names, though, I found that changing the path separator to '/' makes the FileOutputStream throw a NotADirectory error even though 'meditation-files' exists, but it works fine when I use '//' instead. Any ideas as to why? Or is behavior with hypenated names kind of unpredictable in Java?

Comment: Wait, scratch my prior comment. It now works fine when I use either '/' or '\\' when the file names don't have hypens, so now I'm even more confused since I don't think it was working before. But hey, it's working now.